# Why are my ModSecurity rule exceptions being ignored?

Tags: debian, apache-http-server

This might be an obvious issue for some, but I can't figure why ModSec is ignoring my rule exception.

I am using Debian 10 and an SSL secured URL for Monit monitoring software, that works on `www.example.com:3286` which as, verified by my Apache2 error logs, triggers modsec rule id 920350 thereby blocking my access to the Monit web interface.

I used this command to append the rule exception to `modsecurity.conf`:

```
echo "SecRuleRemoveById 920350" >> /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf
```

I went back and verified its presence. Then restarted Apache but the rule ignored.

So then, I tried adding the exception directly to the vhost of `www.example.com` using:

```
<ifModule mod_security2.c>
    SecRuleRemoveById 920350
</ifModule>
```

Then restarted Apache again, and the exception was ignored again.

What am I missing?

**Additional Info**

File/Folder Structure of /etc/modsecurity:

- `crs` - subfolder
- `modsecurity.conf` - file
- `modsecurity.conf-recommended` - file
- `RESPONSE-999-EXCLUSION-RULES-AFTER-CRS` - file
- `unicode.mapping` - file
- `crs` - subfolder content
- `crs-setup.conf` - file
- `REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf` - file
- `RESPONSE-999-EXCLUSION-RULES-AFTER-CRS.conf` - file

Also, as requested: my edited vhost file:

```
# cat 100-example.com.vhost

<Directory /var/www/example.com>
  AllowOverride None
  Require all denied
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>

  DocumentRoot /var/www/clients/client5/web6/web

  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

  ErrorLog /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/example.com/error.log

  <Directory /var/www/example.com/web>
    # Clear PHP settings of this website
    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
      SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
    Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/clients/client5/web6/web>
    # Clear PHP settings of this website
    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
      SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
    Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <IfModule mod_python.c>
    <Directory /var/www/example.com/web>
      <FilesMatch "\.py$">
      SetHandler mod_python
      </FilesMatch>
      PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
      PythonDebug On
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client5/web6/web>
      <FilesMatch "\.py$">
      SetHandler mod_python
      </FilesMatch>
      PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
      PythonDebug On
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>

  # cgi enabled
  <Directory /var/www/clients/client5/web6/cgi-bin>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ScriptAlias  /cgi-bin/ /var/www/clients/client5/web6/cgi-bin/
  <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|pl)$">
  SetHandler cgi-script
  </FilesMatch>
  # suexec enabled
  <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
    SuexecUserGroup web1 client1
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client5/web6/cgi-bin>
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/example.com/web>
      <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
      <If "-f '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}'">
      SetHandler php-fcgi
      </If>
      </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client5/web6/web>
      <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
      <If "-f '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}'">
      SetHandler php-fcgi
      </If>
      </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>
    Action php-fcgi /php-fcgi virtual
    Alias /php-fcgi /var/www/clients/client5/web6/cgi-bin/php-fcgi-*-80-example.com
    FastCgiExternalServer /var/www/clients/client5/web6/cgi-bin/php-fcgi-*-80-example.com -idle-timeout 300 -socket /var/lib/php7.3-fpm/web1.sock -pass-header Authorization  -pass-header Content-Type
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
    #ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php[345]?(/.*)?)$ unix:///var/lib/php7.3-fpm/web1.sock|fcgi://localhost//var/www/clients/client5/web6/web/$1
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client5/web6/web>
      <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
        <If "-f '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}'">
          SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/lib/php7.3-fpm/web1.sock|fcgi://localhost"
        </If>
      </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>


  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
  RewriteRule ^ - [END]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

  # add support for apache mpm_itk
  <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
    AssignUserId web1 client1
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    # Do not execute PHP files in webdav directory
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client5/web6/webdav>
    <ifModule mod_security2.c>
      SecRuleRemoveById 960015
      SecRuleRemoveById 960032
      #SecRuleRemoveById 920350
    </ifModule>
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
    SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>
    DavLockDB /var/www/clients/client5/web6/tmp/DavLock
    # DO NOT REMOVE THE COMMENTS!
    # IF YOU REMOVE THEM, WEBDAV WILL NOT WORK ANYMORE!
    # WEBDAV BEGIN
    # WEBDAV END
  </IfModule>

  # skipping apache_directives, as that will be handled by the ssl vhost

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>

  DocumentRoot /var/www/clients/client5/web6/web

  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

  <IfModule mod_http2.c>
    Protocols h2 http/1.1
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_brotli.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType BROTLI_COMPRESS text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript application/xml application/xml+rss application/atom+xml application/json application/x-font-ttf application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/x-icon
  </IfModule>

  ErrorLog /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/example.com/error.log

  <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    # SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
    SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
    # <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Header always add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"
    # </IfModule>
    SSLCertificateFile /var/www/clients/client5/web6/ssl/example.com-le.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/clients/client5/web6/ssl/example.com-le.key
    SSLUseStapling on
    SSLStaplingResponderTimeout 5
    SSLStaplingReturnResponderErrors off
  </IfModule>

  <Directory /var/www/example.com/web>
    # Clear PHP settings of this website
    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
      SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
    Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/clients/client5/web6/web>
    # Clear PHP settings of this website
    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
      SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
    Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>


  <IfModule mod_python.c>
    <Directory /var/www/example.com/web>
      <FilesMatch "\.py$">
        SetHandler mod_python
      </FilesMatch>
      PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
      PythonDebug On
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client5/web6/web>
      <FilesMatch "\.py$">
        SetHandler mod_python
      </FilesMatch>
      PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
      PythonDebug On
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>

  # cgi enabled
  <Directory /var/www/clients/client5/web6/cgi-bin>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ScriptAlias  /cgi-bin/ /var/www/clients/client5/web6/cgi-bin/
  <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|pl)$">
    SetHandler cgi-script
  </FilesMatch>
  # suexec enabled
  <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
    SuexecUserGroup web1 client1
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client5/web6/cgi-bin>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/example.com/web>
      <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
        <If "-f '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}'">
          SetHandler php-fcgi
        </If>
      </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client5/web6/web>
      <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
        <If "-f '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}'">
          SetHandler php-fcgi
        </If>
      </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>
    Action php-fcgi /php-fcgi virtual
    Alias /php-fcgi /var/www/clients/client5/web6/cgi-bin/php-fcgi-*-443-example.com
    FastCgiExternalServer /var/www/clients/client5/web6/cgi-bin/php-fcgi-*-443-example.com -idle-timeout 300 -socket /var/lib/php7.3-fpm/web1.sock -pass-header Authorization  -pass-header Content-Type
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
    #ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php[345]?(/.*)?)$ unix:///var/lib/php7.3-fpm/web1.sock|fcgi://localhost//var/www/clients/client5/web6/web/$1
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client5/web6/web>
      <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
        <If "-f '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}'">
          SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/lib/php7.3-fpm/web1.sock|fcgi://localhost"
        </If>
      </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>


  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
  RewriteRule ^ - [END]

  # add support for apache mpm_itk
  <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
    AssignUserId web1 client1
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
  # Do not execute PHP files in webdav directory
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client5/web6/webdav>
      <ifModule mod_security2.c>
        SecRuleRemoveById 960015
        SecRuleRemoveById 960032
      </ifModule>
      <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
        SetHandler None
      </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>
    DavLockDB /var/www/clients/client5/web6/tmp/DavLock
    # DO NOT REMOVE THE COMMENTS!
    # IF YOU REMOVE THEM, WEBDAV WILL NOT WORK ANYMORE!
    # WEBDAV BEGIN
    # WEBDAV END
  </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
 SSLStaplingCache shmcb:/var/run/ocsp(128000)
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the rule is in the right place? Did you see if there is already a ModSecurity config area in the `www.example.com` VHost config?

Comment: yes, it is in the correct place... There was already ModSec config area in the vhost (with other rules that seem to work) I merely added my rule, but it is ignored.

Comment: And  are you sure it is the VHost for port 3286? Remember, Apache is on ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS).

Comment: not sure what you mean.  monit requires its own port during set-up.  I have the port opened in my firewall.  and the same setup works on my test server (no modsec, no ssl).  on my prod server modsec is blocking the url because it includes a port number

Comment: Can you possibly share the configs? Neuter personal / server specific stuff that would identify you if you can, but I think full configs would help. Apache Virtual Host configs are specific to a port. Maybe if you have the rule in the general `/etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf` it should cover all configs. But whatever specific Virtual Host config you have it is always specific to a specific port. Like `<VirtualHost *:80>` or `<VirtualHost *:443>`. The point being that if Monit is on `3286` then maybe the issue is the config needs to be set in a config for `<VirtualHost *:3286 >`? An idea.

Comment: I added the edited vhost and modsecurity directory info above

Comment: Thanks for adding that! I think I see your issue. Unless this is some crazy setup — it’s just a website, right? — you are placing your ModSecurity rules in the wrong place: `<Directory /var/www/clients/client5/web6/webdav>`. They should be in the `<Directory /var/www/example.com/web>` areas that are not within the `<IfModule>` checks or just right within the top `<VirtualHost>` areas right after stuff like `ErrorLog`. Try it and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130196/discussion-between-yupthatguy-and-giacomo1968).

Comment: Sorry, but this is not my job. And this is the weekend. I do not provide live support on Stack Exchange sites. Hope you figure this out!